# How to get the type of a template argument when it consists of a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

The first condition operates correctly if t is a char* or a class which overrides operator char *() implicitly or explicitly. The goal of the second condition is to execute the code within the brackets when type t is a pointer and the dereferenced type of t can be converted to a char *. The second condition does not hold true when it should (ex. t is char** should evaluate to true). What am I doing wrong?

F.Y.I.: I'm only concerned with a single pointer to something that is convertible to a char * like char ** and not concerned with char ***, if that makes sense.

```
 t * Find(char * name)
            {
                if (std::is_convertible<t, char*>::value)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (std::is_convertible<typename std::remove_pointer<t>::type, char * >::value)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                static_assert(false, "VSarray<T>::Find(char *), T is not convertable to a char *");
            }
```

Comment: If you're basing failure on the static assertion, it's going to fire every time regardless of which branch would have been taken.

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that demonstrates your problem? Also, the conditions of your `if`s being compile time constants will not prevent your static_assert from always firing.

Comment: @chris you were right, I must have changed the condition inside the static assertion before retesting.

Comment: @melak47 I figured out the problem on my end I can post the full function including code inside the condition brackets, do you know if I post it under my original post or as an answer?

Comment: @user3141117, If you figure out the problem yourself or have a Q&A you feel would be useful to others, you're more than welcome to answer your own question. That doesn't lower the bar for answer quality, though.

Answer (score 0):

Works as intended. The static assertion makes sure type t(from template argument) is convertible to a char *. The function is separated into two functions to allow type t to be dereferenced when it is a pointer to a type that can be converted to a char *.

```
    #define CHECK_TYPE_CONVERSION(TYPEFROM,TYPETO) std::is_convertible<TYPEFROM, TYPETO>::value
#define CHECK_POINTER_TYPE_CONVERSION(TYPEFROM,TYPETO) std::is_convertible<std::remove_pointer<TYPEFROM>::type,TYPETO>::value
    t * Find(char * name)
    {
        static_assert(CHECK_TYPE_CONVERSION(t,char*) || CHECK_POINTER_TYPE_CONVERSION(t,char*)
             , "T cannot be converted to a char *");
        if (CHECK_TYPE_CONVERSION(t,char*) == false)
            return this->FindFromPointer(name);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->arraySize_; i++)
        {
            char * str = (char*)this->arrayData_[i];
            if (strcmp(str, name) == 0)
                return &this->arrayData_[i];
        }
        return 0;

    }


private:
    t * FindFromPointer(char * name)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->arraySize_; i++)
        {
            char * str = (char*)*this->arrayData_[i];
            if (strcmp(str, name) == 0)
                return &this->arrayData_[i];
        }
        return 0;
    }
```